# JS: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, import, export

I'm having a problem when import a Class outside its folder in Js. Here's my directory tree:

[image: Directory tree]

When I try to import Class1 from Client, there's an error occurs:

[image: Import Error]

Client/index.js:

```js
export { default as Class1 } from "./Class1";
```

Client/Class1.js:

```js
class Class1 {
    static hello() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}

export default Class1;
```

Please help, many thanks!

Comment: Your code here says `export`, the screenshot says `import`.

Comment: The index.js file in the screenshot is in the root folder.

Comment: What does that have to do with my comment? Your code snippet says `export {default as Class1}`, but the screenshot says `import { Class1 }`. Why don't they match?